# How to solve Google Fabrics crash - Fatal Exception: DeviceNotSupported?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, google-fabric

I keep getting crashes on `Fabric` for my iOS App.

> Fatal Exception: DeviceNotSupportedException: Device Not Supported

At the signature of the function,

```
+(NSString*) IPHONE_OS_VERSION // Fabric pointed lines
{
    // code
}
```

[image]

I never heard of `DeviceNotSupportedException`. What is the crash for? how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

When a Objective-C or C++ exception goes uncaught, Crashlytics records some information about it before the app is allowed to terminate. When this happens, the CLSProcessRecordAllThreads function must be run on the thread that threw the exception. This means that in the case of an exception, the “crashing” thread will always look like it is running Crashlytics code. This is normal, and is just an artifact of how Crashlytics capture and present the stack traces at the time of exception.

Reference from Fabric doc [here](http://%20When%20a%20Objective-C%20or%20C++%20exception%20goes%20uncaught,%20Crashlytics%20records%20some%20information%20about%20it%20before%20the%20app%20is%20allowed%20to%20terminate.%20When%20this%20happens,%20the%20CLSProcessRecordAllThreads%20function%20must%20be%20run%20on%20the%20thread%20that%20threw%20the%20exception.%20This%20means%20that%20in%20the%20case%20of%20an%20exception,%20the%20%E2%80%9Ccrashing%E2%80%9D%20thread%20will%20always%20look%20like%20it%20is%20running%20Crashlytics%20code.%20This%20is%20normal,%20and%20is%20just%20an%20artifact%20of%20how%20we%20capture%20and%20present%20the%20stack%20traces%20at%20the%20time%20of%20exception.)

Comment: My question was about the reason of device not supported exception.